# Validate password against its username in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a log in form on Access that will allow a user to log in if they enter any username and any password from the Login table. It does not check if the username and password are matched to each other. How do I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Command4_Click()

If IsNull(Me.txtLog) Then
MsgBox "Please enter username", vbInformation, "Username required"
Me.txtLog.SetFocus

ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPass) Then
MsgBox "Please enter password", vbInformation, "Password required"
Me.txtPass.SetFocus

Else
'checking Password And UserName
If (IsNull(DLookup("Username", "Login", "Username = '" & Me.txtLog.Value & "'"))) Or _
(IsNull(DLookup("Password", "Login", "Password = '" & Me.txtPass.Value & "'"))) Then
MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"

Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"

End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether any row matches both the username and password.

```vb
Dim strCriteria As String
strCriteria = "Username = '" & Me.txtLog.Value & _
    "' AND [Password] = '" & Me.txtPass.Value & "'"
Debug.Print strCriteria '<- view this in Immediate window; Ctrl+g will take you there
If DCount("*", "[Login]", strCriteria) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Incorrect Username or Password"
Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main Menu"
End If
```

Comment: Worked perfect. Thank you